# Wordpressサイトのトップページが表示されない

Tags: wordpress

以下の件、お分かりになる方ご教示くだされば幸いです。

発生事象：
Wordpressサイトのトップページが表示されない。

対象URL： https://www.tamakotu.com/hino/
Wordpressインストールディレクトリ： /hino/
Wordpress設定（管理画面＞設定）：
WordPress アドレス (URL)： https://www.tamakotu.com/hino
サイトアドレス（URL)： https://www.tamakotu.com/hino

htaccessの記述：

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /hino/
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /hino/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

本来はこうなるはずなのです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/041bwzeodkg9r3) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)